# MySQL query to sum data and group by hour from unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a MySQL table with 3 columns:

- **`id`** (as primary key)
- **`amount`** (int)
- **`data_time`** (bigint), where the `date_time` column store unix timestamp.

I **need a query when run it show me on output 24 row and each row contain 3 columns** just like below :

------ column1 -------------------------------- column2 -------------------------------------------- column3 -------

row1: 0-1 * sum of all **amount** column on all day hour 00:00 to 01:00 * count of rows in this hour

row2: 1-2 * sum of all **amount** column on all day hour 01:00 to 02:00 * count of rows in this hour

row3: 2-3 * sum of all **amount** column on all day hour 02:00 to 03:00 * count of rows in this hour

....

row24: 23-0 * sum of all **amount** column on all day hour 23:00 to 00:00 * count of rows in this hour

**This query needs to run within the start and the end of the timestamp range and may contain few days then we need this data calc for all day on a mentioned hour.**

For example, start timestamp is 1511296200 and end is 1512592140 difference is 15 day.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any SQL that you have written to try to do this?

Comment: i dont have any idea

Comment: Little hint: `GROUP BY HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(data_time))`

Comment: thanks @RaymondNijland but your way ignore some hour if not have record
i need to show all hours whether 0 rows

Comment: You need to create a calender table or deliverd table with numbers 0 - 23 and use a LEFT JOIN

Comment: @RaymondNijland
how can join on calculated column hour ?